# How to compute the percentage of improvement

Tags: percentages

Sorry if my question is obvious, but I really need to know the answer. I have proposed a load balancing algorithm for decreasing the value of response time. For example imagine the response time of algorithm1 is $120$ seconds and my proposed algorithm has decreased this value to $25$ seconds. Now I want to compute the percentage of this improvement. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage of improvement often does not work like people think, so I don't like the term, but we can calculate it.  You were doing $\frac 1{120}$ of the task per second.  You are now doing $\frac 1{25}$ of the task per second.  The improvement is $\frac 1{25}-\frac 1{120}=\frac {19}{600}$ of the task per second.  This is $\frac {19}5$ of the amount you were doing, so the improvement is $380\%$

By contrast, the time required is $\frac {25}{120}=\frac 5{24}$ of the time taken previously, so the time has been reduced by $\frac {19}{24}$ and the time reduction is about $79\%$.  Be careful to define what number you are quoting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way I didn't exactly understand what is $19/5$, where does $5$ come from? By the way, in a research paper should we use the second value ($79%$) for showing the better performance?

Comment: The $5$ is from dividing $600$ by $120$.  You can use either number but need to carefully specify what it means.  One is how much more you do in a given time, the other is how much less time it takes to do the job.